# Reverse linked list from position left to right

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, runtime-error, singly-linked-list

I'm getting run time error and I don't know why. I tried backtracking but couldn't figure out. please help!

Constraints given:

1. The number of nodes in the list is n.
2. 1 <= n <= 500
3. -500 <= Node.val <= 500
4. 1 <= left <= right <= n

> =================================================================
> ==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000098 at pc 0x000000370bdd bp 0x7ffdce3742a0 sp
> 0x7ffdce374298
> READ of size 8 at 0x602000000098 thread T0
> #2 0x7fe06dce80b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
> 0x602000000098 is located 8 bytes inside of 16-byte region [0x602000000090,0x6020000000a0)
> freed by thread T0 here:
> #3 0x7fe06dce80b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
> previously allocated by thread T0 here:
> #4 0x7fe06dce80b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
> Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
> 0x0c047fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 0x0c047fff8000: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fd
> =>0x0c047fff8010: fa fa fd[fd]fa fa fd fd fa fa 00 00 fa fa fd fd
> 0x0c047fff8020: fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fd fa fa fd fd fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c047fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
> Addressable:           00
> Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
> Heap left redzone:       fa
> Freed heap region:       fd
> Stack left redzone:      f1
> Stack mid redzone:       f2
> Stack right redzone:     f3
> Stack after return:      f5
> Stack use after scope:   f8
> Global redzone:          f9
> Global init order:       f6
> Poisoned by user:        f7
> Container overflow:      fc
> Array cookie:            ac
> Intra object redzone:    bb
> ASan internal:           fe
> Left alloca redzone:     ca
> Right alloca redzone:    cb
> Shadow gap:              cc
> ==31==ABORTING

Definition for singly-linked list.

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};

class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int left, int right) {
        ListNode *h=head;
        if(left!=right) {
            for(int i=1;i<left-1;++i) 
            {
                h=h->next;
            }
            ListNode *fr=NULL;
            ListNode *prev=h;
            h=h->next;
            for(int j=left;j<=right;++j)
            {
                fr=h->next;
                h->next=prev;
                prev=h;
                h=fr;
            }
            head->next->next=prev->next;
            head->next=prev;
            //h=prev;
            return head;
        }
        else {
            return head;
        }
        
        
    }
};
```

Comment: Write some simple local test cases and run them, find the simplest test case that fails and then debug it.  What you're doing here seems to be using some unknown-size data, hitting a bug then dumping it on other people to try to resolve.

Comment: `head->next->next=prev->next` you are setting the second element's next without considering the values `left` and `right`. Why? (...why always the second?)

Comment: @dratenik, so will a third variable, let's say `ListNode *temp=prev`  after initializing prev help ? and then `temp->next->next=prev->next` and `temp->next=prev` accordingly. Let me know if you have any better approach to this.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, Thanks for your inputs! I'll keep that in mind when posting other questions.

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Anyway, let's consider the case left=1. To connect the reversed portion here, there is no `->next` you could access. Some kind of pointer could be helpful here, but it might be time to go double star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some points to take care of:

- Check whether a `next` reference is not a null pointer before dereferencing it. For example: never do `head->next->next=`, as you generally don't know whether `head->next` is not a null pointer. This is the cause of the errors you get.
- `head->next = prev;` will not do the right thing, unless the reversal started at the second node. But in all other cases this is wrong. You need a reference to the node that precedes the section that reversed.
- You didn't cover the case where the reversal starts at node 1 and thus you need to return a different reference than the one you got as argument.
- Although the task description guarantees that `left` and `right` are within range, I would add some minimal sanity checks on the `left` and `right` arguments. It doesn't cost more than 2 lines of code.

Here is the proposed solution:

```
ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int left, int right) {
    if (left < 1) left = 1;
    if (!head || left >= right) return head;
    ListNode *h = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < left - 1; ++i) {
        h = h->next;
        if (!head) return head;
    }
    ListNode *prev = left > 1 ? h->next : h;
    if (!prev) return head;
    ListNode *unmoved = left > 1 ? h : nullptr;
    ListNode *moved = prev;
    h = prev->next;
    for (int j = left + 1; j <= right && h; ++j) {
        ListNode * fr = h->next;
        h->next = prev;
        prev = h;
        h = fr;
    }
    moved->next = h;
    if (unmoved) {
        unmoved->next = prev;
        return head;
    } else {
        return prev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is, you reference a previous node and create a loop, and some other nodes are still located in your memory but no longer addressed in code. Usually a garbage collector would clean this up, but in C++ you gotta manage memory allocation yourself.

I adjusted your logic a bit, to stop it from creating a loop
(variables are renamed)

```
ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int left, int right) {
  ListNode* current = head;
  if (left != right) {
    for (int i = 1; i < left - 1; ++i)
    {
      current = current->next;
    }
    
    ListNode* ankerLeft = left == 1 ? nullptr : current;
    ListNode* ankerRight = current->next;
    
    ListNode* nextNode = nullptr;
    ListNode* prevNode = ankerRight;
    
    for (int j = left-1; j <= right; ++j)
    {
      if (current != nullptr) {
        nextNode = current->next;
        current->next = prevNode;
        prevNode = current;
        current = nextNode;
      }
    }

    if (ankerLeft != nullptr) {
      ankerLeft->next = prevNode;
      ankerRight->next = current;
    }
    else {
      head->next = current;
      head = prevNode;
    }

    return head;
  }
  else {
    return head;
  }
}
```

This also enables to reverse the whole list now. (Thanks to @dratenik for commenting)

This works fine for me and shouldn't lose you any reserved memory

---

**Edit:**

After reading into your logic a bit more, the only thing you were missing was a reference, to the last node of your reversed list, to correctly connect to the original list again
`head->next->next = prev->next;` will not give you the correct node, since you already have overwritten the node, I included an anker in your code, to keep an reference to the last node of the reversing algorithm. Also `prev->next` is the wrong node to reference your end to, since `prev->next` already is reversed it will return the wrong node.

Here is your code with an anker added, your reverse algorithm works fine, I adjusted the after logic a bit and now it should work fine.

```
ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int left, int right) {
  ListNode* h = head;
  if (left != right) {
  for (int i = 1; i < left - 1; ++i)
  {
    h = h->next;
  }
  ListNode* fr = NULL;
  ListNode* prev = h;
  ListNode* ankerRight = h->next;
  h = h->next;
  for (int j = left; j <= right; ++j)
  {
    fr = h->next;
    h->next = prev;
    prev = h;
    h = fr;
  }
  // this would overwrite the wrong reference and create a loop
  // head->next->next = prev->next;

  head->next = prev;
  ankerRight->next = h;
  return head;
  }
  else {
    return head;
  }
}
```

Your logic still fails in case you want to reverse the whole list.

Hope I could help and explained everything clearly.

Comment: Conuterexample: reverseBetween([10,20,30],1,3) - expected [30,20,10], actual result:segfault

Comment: @dratenik Ohh, you are correct, the logic works excpet if you try to reverse the whole list, I'll take a look into it.

Comment: @dratenik fixed the problem, now everything is working as intended, thanks for your response

Comment: This never moves the first node, even when `left=1`.

Comment: @trincot in case you want to start left = 1, the first node will be the node on the right, so we have no anker, if you we want to start from node 2, you still want the head as reference, so it makes sense to not move the first node when for example you reverse (2,5)

Comment: @trincot I don't exactly understand what you mean, I tested it and it works fine for me, even for the first node

Comment: The function is supposed to return the new head in case the first node is part of the range that reverses. For instance `reverseBetween([1,2,3], 1, 2)` should return a reference to the list [2,1,3], but your code reverses the nodes at position 2 and 3. (According to the question, `left` and `right` range between 1 and `n`, so they are 1-based positions).

Comment: @sschwei1, thanks for the help and your input!